# Proof of Theorem 4.6 (Primitive Element Theorem) in Lang's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

The following shows how Lang proved a statement as a part of the primitive element theorem, which asserts that if a finite extension $E$ of a field $k$ is separable over $k$, then there exists an element $α∈E$ such that $E = k (α)$.

[image]

I am confused by the following argument, which is also highlighted in the picture above:

Then the elements $σ_{i}(α + cβ) (i = 1, ... , n)$ are distinct, whence
$k(α + cβ)$ has degree at least $n$ over $k$.

I can't see how one can estimate the degree of $k(α+cβ)/k$ using the fact that the $n$ values $σ_{i}(α + cβ) (i = 1, ... , n)$ are distinct. I assume this is because the polynomial $$\prod_{i=1}^n (X - \sigma_{i}(\alpha+c\beta))$$ divides $Irr(\alpha+c\beta, k, X)$ (i.e. the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha+c\beta$ over $k$) but I can't either prove or disprove the latter statement. Can anyone help me to show how we can estimate the degree of the field extension $k(\alpha+c\beta)/k$ in this context, no matter if it is proved by using  $Irr(\alpha+c\beta, k, X)$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The degree is $n$ and the automorphisms act transitively on the roots. If it were factorizable as $p(x)q(x)$, the automorphisms would permute the roots of $p$ amongst themselves and the roots of $q(x)$ amongst themselves. The fact that the action is transitive therefore tells you there is no such factorization over $k$.

Comment: Because the elements $\sigma_1(\alpha + c\beta), \dots, \sigma_n(\alpha + c\beta)$ are distinct, there are at least $n$ different $k$-linear embeddings $\sigma_1|_{k(\alpha + c\beta)}, \dots, \sigma_n|_{k(\alpha + c\beta)}$ of ${k(\alpha + c\beta)}$ into $k^\ast$, so the separation degree is at least $n$, so the field degree is at least $n$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for you help. I think I do understand now.

Comment: @CarloK.  Thank you for your help too. I was too unfamiliar with separable extensions that I completely ignore the relation between the separation degree and the field degree.